# How can I join the cell values from two pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

How can I join the cell values from two pandas dataframe?

```
df1 is:

         F1   F2   M1   M2
    pos
    23  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
    24  1.0  1.0  1.5  1.0
    28  1.0  0.0  0.5  0.0


df2 is:

         F1   F2   M1   M2
    pos
    23  0.0  1.0  0.5  0.0
    24  1.0  1.0  1.5  1.0
    28  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

How can I combine the values (which have same `column` and `row` indexes) inside these dataframe with a comma?

**Expected output like:**

```
         F1       F2       M1       M2
    pos
    23  1.0,0.0  0.0,1.0  1.0,0.5  1.0,0.0
    24  1.0,1.0  1.0,1.0  1.5,1.5  1.0,1.0
same for other lines...
The value of df1 should be place before comma and df2 after that.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sum them up as two DFs with "string" elements:

```
In [324]: d1.astype(str).add(',').add(d2.astype(str))
Out[324]:
          F1       F2       M1       M2
pos
23   1.0,0.0  0.0,1.0  1.0,0.5  1.0,0.0
24   1.0,1.0  1.0,1.0  1.5,1.5  1.0,1.0
28   1.0,0.0  0.0,1.0  0.5,1.0  0.0,1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but What about the `pos` index value? I have more than one column that are set as index and would like to retain them aswell.

Comment: @everestial007, this should work also for multiindex DFs

Comment: in fact it did. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxU - I like your solution +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `DataFrames`, cast to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and `groupby` by `index` with aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) function `join`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
df.index.name = df1.index.name
print (df)
          F1       F2       M1       M2
pos                                    
23   1.0,0.0  0.0,1.0  1.0,0.5  1.0,0.0
24   1.0,1.0  1.0,1.0  1.5,1.5  1.0,1.0
28   1.0,0.0  0.0,1.0  0.5,1.0  0.0,1.0
```

Comment: the pos index is lost. Infact there will be lots of other indexes too. How can I retain them back?

Comment: I like this answer a little more because I think it's a little more general in terms of how you want your cells concatenated. For example, I wanted my cells to be combined as a tuple, so I just replaced `','.join` with `tuple` in the `agg` method.